# Image not displaying outside div

Tags: css

I have an image positioned absolute inside a div. For some reason it does not display outside the div. How can I display the part outside div?

```
<div class="page-section page-section--large page-section--work-1 page-section--alternating">
    <div class="page-width">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item medium-up--four-eighths medium-up--push-four-eighths">
          <div class="alternating-title-wrapper">
            <h2 class="h1 alternating-title">
                            <svg class="icon icon-shape-diamond " aria-hidden="true"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shape-diamond"></use></svg>            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="alternating-content">
            <p class="selectionShareable"></p>
            <div class="partners-logos">
              <svg class="icon icon-magento-logo " aria-hidden="true"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#magento-logo"></use></svg>              <svg class="icon icon-weblinc-logo " aria-hidden="true"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#weblinc-logo"></use></svg>              <svg class="icon icon-shopify-logo " aria-hidden="true"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shopify-logo"></use></svg>            </div>
            <a href="/partners" class="btn btn--secondary ">Partners page</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://staging.demacmedia.com/wp-content/themes/demac_media/assets/images/work-snuggle.png" class="alternating-image alternating-image--work-1" alt="Demac's partners">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.alternating-image {
    display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 750px)
_quotes.scss:281
.alternating-image {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
_page-products.scss:18
.alternating-image--work-1 {
    bottom: -25%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

### Edit

I tried:

```
overflow: visible;
```

on the div but it does not work:

[image]

Comment: Could you post the css as well? Its difficult to resolve css issues without the css ;)

Comment: The css file is too big. I think people will mind seeing such a big css file.

Comment: just add the part of the CSS that is giving error, like the container of the elements, the image... not all!

Comment: @FahadUddin that doesn't reproduce the problem. Create a [mcve] that reproduces your problem with a layout that cuts off the image, and working images please.